# Laravel - Retrieve just the rows for the parent relation in a nested whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models with Relations. There relations are like this

```
Sites
Tenancies
Tenants

1 site can have many tenancies
1 tenancy can have 1 tenant
```

I'm getting a collection of all of the tenants that have a tenancy for that site, by using a `hasManyThrough` relationship like this

```
public function tenants(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Tenants\Tenants',
        'App\Models\Tenancies\Tenancies',
        'site_id', // Foreign key on Tenancies table...
        'id', // Foreign key on invoices table...
        'id', // Local key on tenants table...
        'linked_tenant_id' // Local key on tenancies table...
    )->distinct();
}
```

And then getting only active tenancies like this

```
public function activeTenancies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tenancies\Tenancies', 'linked_tenant_id', 'id')->where('active',1);
}
```

And then calling it like this

```
    $sites = Sites::whereHas('tenants')->with(['tenants' => function($query){
        $query->whereHas('activeTenancies')->with('activeTenancies');
    }]);
```

This works great, if i then dd the collection, it returns only the sites that have active tenancies, and then returns the tenants with it.

My issue is that each tenant, can have many tenancies with many sites.

So lets say I have a tenant called FakeComp, and lets say FakeComp has tenancies with both Site 1 and Site 2, like this.

```
Site - 1
Tenancy - TenancyABC
Tenant - FakeComp

Site - 2
Tenancy - TenancyBCA
Tenant - FakeComp
```

When I loop my sites and tenants, as 'FakeComp' has a tenancy with both Site 1 and Site 2, it returns like this

```
Site - 1
  |
  |-----> Fake Comp
              |
              |---------> TenancyABC
              |---------> TenancyBCA

Site - 2
  |
  |-----> Fake Comp
              |
              |---------> TenancyABC
              |---------> TenancyBCA
```

Rather than only getting the tenancies that are for that site, like this

```
Site - 1
  |
  |-----> Fake Comp
              |
              |---------> TenancyABC

Site - 2
  |
  |-----> Fake Comp
              |
              |---------> TenancyBCA
```

FakeComp is being grabbed by both sites, because it has a tenancy with both sites. But then instead of only grabbing the tenancies for that site, its grabbing all of its tenancies.

How do I get ONLY the tenancies for that site? I'm sorry if this is confusing, its quite hard to explain.

Comment: I don't think there's an in-query solution using `with()`. You'll probably have to remove the unwanted models from the query result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a `site_id` on the `tenancies` table, I'm guessing that it refers to the id on `sites` table, so you can just add a relationship on you `Site` model to the `Tenancy` (a simple hasOne or hasMany if a site can have multiple tenancies).

To clarify, you are using a `hasManyThrough` relationship between sites and tenancies so has the relationship name is saying you have many tenants **through** tenancies. Therefor, there **is** a direct relationship between sites and tenancies.